# SSRS Use Query Parameter in Query String PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting-services

How to use query parameter variable in the query string for a PostgreSQL database?

I have a report parameter `Address` that the user types the address. I then want to TRIM and make it upper case, so I created a Parameter in the Dataset Properties named `USER_ADDRESS` with an expression of `TRIM(UCase(Parameters!Address.Value))`

[image: screenshot of report parameter]

[image: screenshot of query parameter]

Previously, I had an oracle databsae and all of this worked by referencing the query parameter like:

`SELECT *  FROM table  WHERE table.address = :USER_ADDRESS`

But now that we're switching, the PostgreSQL doesn't like that syntax.

Comment: For PostgreSQL, I believe you just use a `?` instead of the `:USER_ADDRESS` in the query.

Comment: "PostgreSQL doesn't like that syntax." Can you please post the error that Postgres returns

Comment: yes it does, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, using a `?` as an unnamed parameter for an ODBC connection worked.

```
SELECT *  FROM table  WHERE table.address = ?
```

Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/binding-parameters-odbc?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440344/best-practice-to-pass-parameter-into-dataset-query
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/odbc-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16